# Waiting for a Bukkit Task to Complete in a For Loop

Tags: java, scheduler, minecraft, bukkit

I need some serious help.

Here is my code right now.

```
for (String line : commandStrings) {
    line = line.trim();
    line = line.replaceAll("\\{PLAYERNAME\\}", target.getName());
    util.log(line);
    char[] lineArray = line.toCharArray();
    if (lineArray.length > 1) {
        if (lineArray[0] == '/') {
            String command = util.removeElt(lineArray, 0);
            util.log(command);
            if (!(config.getBoolean("Command Strings." + args[2] + ".delay.firstExecuteDelay")) && count == 0) {
                consoleExecuteTask = getTask(command);
                BukkitTask task = scheduler.runTask(this.plugin, consoleExecuteTask);
                continue;
            } else {
                consoleExecuteTask = getTask(command);
                BukkitTask task = scheduler.runTaskLater(this.plugin, consoleExecuteTask, (delay * 20L));
                util.log("ran later");
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            util.log("Invalid Command : \" " + String.valueOf(lineArray) + " \" in Command String: " + args[2]);
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        continue;
    }

}
sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GREEN + "Command String : " + args[2] + "Executed.");
return true;
```

What it is supposed to do, is get a String list from the config with commands to run and a delay between each of them.
Here is the config for that part,

```
preset2:
  delay:
     global_delay: true
     global_delayString: "10s"
     firstExecuteDelay: true
  commands:
     - "/effect {PLAYERNAME} speed 30 5"
     - "/effect {PLAYERNAME} 16 30 5"
```

When I run the command for the second preset. The problem is that it doesnt wait for the first command to be executed before it moves on to the second commnand in the for loop. How do i make it wait for the first command to be done without freezing the main thread. Here is the important section of the runnable :

```
public consoleExecuteTask(CommandStrings plugin, String command) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    this.command = command;
    plugin.getLogger().info("called");
    running = true;
}

public void run() {
    plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(plugin.getServer().getConsoleSender(),command);
    running = false;
    plugin.getLogger().info("ran " + command);
}
```

Im am using this method to get the task.

```
public static consoleExecuteTask getTask(String line) {
    if (consoleExecuteTask == null) {
        consoleExecuteTask = new consoleExecuteTask(plugin, line);
    }
    return consoleExecuteTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **Scheduler**.

To create a scheduler, you need to create a new BukkitRunnable, then run it:

```
new BukkitRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Execute the commands here one by one.
    }
}.runTaskTimer(mainInstance, 0, delayBetweenCalls);
```

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming

Comment: So how would I get all of the commands into the runnable though? Would I just move the for loop into the new runnable? Also the problem is that for the other half of the code the delay between the commands varies, so do I need to create a runnable every time I go through the loop with the different delays .